# listview trigger('create') doesn't work with jasmine-jquery mobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, jasmine

I have developed an app with jquery-mobile. Now I am trying to setup a jasmine framework for it.

In original code, I am creating a listview dynamically. After appending items to `ul.list`, I 
am calling `ul.list.listview('refresh');`
This is working as expected in main app.

I have added different UTs, to check behavior of different events on this list. So every time I am calling populate function to load this list.
The general structure of my jasmine code is:

```
describe("List behavior", function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
        var obj = new listObj({});
        loadFixtures('list.html');
        $('ul.list').trigger('create');
    });

    it("should ...", function() {
        obj.populate(somelist);
        .
        . 
    });

    it("should ...", function() {
        obj.populate(somelist);
        .
        . 
    });

    it("should ...", function() {
        obj.populate(somelist);
        .
        . 
    });


});
```

Code for populate method is

```
this.populate = function(somelist) {
    $('ul.list').append(somelist).listview('refresh');  
};
```

When the line comes 'listview('refresh')', it gives error as `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'` 
though I am creating listview before each test execution. And then all my succeding tests fail.

Things I tried and their results :
1. I tried just assigning `'ui-listview'` to the `ul.list`, and not creating listview. Still it didn't work.

1. I tried `$('ul.list').listview()`, it gives error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery110203482820538338274' of undefined`. But this assigns required class to the ul.

Can any one suggest me some workaround so that I can execute all tests without this error?
Thanks.

Comment: `$('ul.list').listview().append(somelist).listview('refresh');` or `$('ul.list').append(somelist).listview().listview('refresh');` You need to initialize listview first using `.listview()` before refreshing. Also, it should be appended ahead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But doing this also, its giving me errors like ''Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery11020874638092238456' of undefined''. Basically on initializing listview, its not adding ui-listview class to it.

Comment: check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/X9Wmd/

Comment: This is working great with main code. But when test execution come to `listview('refresh')`, it throws this error.

Comment: are you appending `ul.list` before adding items to it?

Comment: No. I am simply adding list items to `ul.list`.`ul.list` is present in jasmine-fixture.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42408/discussion-between-sonam-and-omar)